# Google charts ChartWrapper chart wrapper arguments options field documentation

Tags: google-visualization

I am new to google charts. I am using ChartWrapper to draw my chart and I am passing a chart wrapper arguments to the constructor when creating a chart like this:

```
var chartWrapperArgs = {
                chartType: "LineChart",
                dataTable: dataTable,
                options: { // <<<< where to find a documentations about this property ?
                    "width": 900,
                    "height": 800,
                    "is3D": true,
                    "title": "Явление на числата ",
                    "isStacked": "false",
//                    "fill": 20,
                    "displayExactValues": false,
                    "vAxis": {
                        "title": "явление"
                    },
                    "hAxis": {
                        "title": "число"
                    }
                },
                containerId: containerId
            };


            var chartWrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper(chartWrapperArgs);
```

My question is where to get a documentations about the "options" parameter ? what option can I pass to "options" ?

I checked out Google documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google.visualization.drawchart) 
but they only describe what option, give simple example and thats all. However I found that in some of there, and others, code example other parameters are used !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The options that are appropriate depend on the chartType, and the documentation for the options is together with the other documentation about the chartType.  See the list at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery

For the LineChart, the options are documented here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options